# Media query: iPad only one orientation works

Tags: ipad, css, responsive-design, media-queries

i'm currently having troubly with a site that i'm converting to a adaptive-website. For some reason i can only get one of the orientations to work on the iPad. If i comment out the landscape styling the portrait styling works on the ipad and visa versa. I really don't understand what it is that i am doing wrong...

These are the media queries that i am using:

```
@media all and (device-width : 768px) and (orientation: landscape) {}
@media all and (min-device-width:768px) and (max-device-width:1024px) and (orientation:portrait){}
```

Here is a link to the site [www.imarken.dk](http://www.imarken.dk/?page_id=37)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `min-device-width`. Try to use 481 instead 768.

Answer (score 0):

Give these a whirl:

```
@media only screen and (device-width: 768px) {
  /* targets iPad  */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {
  /* targets iPad Portrait */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
 /* targets iPad Landscape */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem today! As it turns out, removing my height=device-height in the meta viewport tag fixed the issue and allowed the CSS to switch between portrait and landscape as expected. Hope this helps!